# Force file download in WordPress

Tags: hooks

I am trying to create a script so that I can pass file id as a querystring to /download.php url and it do the force downloading of that file.
The url should look like http://website.com/download.php?file=123

Below is my code but it leads me to either 404 page or shows ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

```php
/**
 * Download File from ID
 */
add_action('template_redirect','cityportal_force_download');
function cityportal_force_download() {
    if ($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']=='/download.php' && isset($_GET['file']) && !empty($_GET['file'])) {
        $file_id = $_GET['file'];
    $file_path = get_attached_file($file_id);
        $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url($file_id);
        
        if(file_exists($file_path)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($file_path));
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
            flush();
            readfile($file_url);
            die();

            exit;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: `readfile($file_url)` - that should be `readfile($file_path)` ..

Comment: tried that aswell. same error. I think I have to register a route for download.php some way

Comment: Yes, you could register a custom rewrite rule or maybe a custom REST API endpoint... But as I said in my answer, you could also just use the `parse_request` hook and your code would work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because WordPress attempted to parse the request which means WordPress tries to find a resource such as a post or category archive which matches the request URL (`/download.php`), and when not found, WordPress sets the HTTP status header to *404 Not Found*.

So to fix the issue, you could use [`parse_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) instead of `template_redirect`, or call [`status_header()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/status_header/) when you set the other headers. E.g.

```php
if(file_exists($file_path)) {
    status_header( 200 );

    // ... your code.
}
```

And BTW, as I said in the comments, you should use `readfile($file_path)` — just a reminder..

Comment: Using 'parse_request' instead of 'template_redirect' worked for me.